# Go to Error List after build

Tags: visual-c++

When I press <kbd>F7</kbd> in MSVC++ 2010 and the build returns errors, the process stays on the output window.

Is there an option to make it go to the Error List instead after building?

[image: from output window to error list window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Options dialog, navigate in the left tree to *Projects and Solutions > General*. There, you will find a check box named *Always show Error List if build finishes with errors*.

Check that box.

Comment: The opposite of this has been driving me insane for years... why, oh why, have I only just thought to search for an answer.  Thanks!